# Permutations/Combinations and Multiset

Tags: combinatorics

I've recently been studying about combinations and permutations and am confused about the different techniques to use to solve different problems. For example, question 1 v.s. question 2:

Question 1:
The number of ways to distribute $26$ indistinguishable pens to $7$ different students so that each student will have at least one pen.

Question 2:
The number of ways to distribute $3$ balls to $5$ boxes.

For question 1, I first distributed 7 pens to the 7 different students. Then I applied the multiset technique for the remaining 19 pens. I used the bar and crosses technique and got the answer of $\binom{19 + 7 - 1}{7 - 1}$.

I tried using the same technique for the second question but it didn't seem to work which made me confused about when to use the multiset formula $\binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1}$ and when to just use the normal permutation/combination equations. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In the second problem, you have not stated whether the balls are distinct or indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty good question.

Note that the given 26 pens are indistinguishable/identical. Solving this problem is equivalent to find the number of solutions to the following equation:

$x_1+ x_2+...........+x_7 =26$ where each $x_x \geq 1.$  The number of such solutions is

$\binom {26-1} {7-1}.$ The explanation/trick you have mentioned for the first problem, is correct.

Note the second problem is totally different in the following sense: All the balls are different/distinct. Let me explain why you cannot use the previous idea for this problem.

In the first problem, $$1pen +1pen = 2 pens$$ this innocent-looking statement is true. This basically says $x+x=2x.$ However, in the second problem, you cannot say $$ 1 ball +  \mathbb{ 1ball} =2 balls$$ because $x+y$ is just $x+y$ nothing else. What I am saying the trick of the first problem cannot be applied to the second problem. For the second problem, the number of such distribution is $5^3$ because for each distinct ball, there are $5$ choices. Finally, say we have two distinct balls, say $a$ and $b.$ and three boxes /places. Then $ab\circ$ and $ba\circ$ are two different distributions. The first one means $a$ was placed in the first box, $b$ was placed in the second box, and no ball in the third box. The second distribution has a similar interpretation. Note that if we treat these balls identical, then these two distributions would be the same, which is the case in the first problem. In that case, to solve problem 2, you can use the trick you have mentioned.