# Relationship between combinations number and multiset permutations number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I saw questions and answers, similar to what I'm going to ask - for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123820/permutations-combinations-and-multiset) one. However it seems to me, my question will be different, and even simpler. I'll describe it with the following example.

**Problem 1**. We have a set of four *distinguishable* objects and we want to count a number of different *unordered* subsets of this set with two elements. For example, for $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ these subsets are $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}$. The number of them obviously is $\binom{4}{2}$.

**Problem 2**. We have a set of four objects, consisting of two pairs of *undistinguishable* objects (a multiset). We want to count a number of *ordered* permutations of these objects. For example, the string "aabb" can be permuted by six ways: "aabb", "abab", "abba", "baab", "baba", "bbaa". The number of permutations is of course $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$.

So, in both cases we get the same count, and I think it isn't accidental - but I don't see any one-to-one meaningful mapping between the sets in the Problem 1 and in the Problem 2. It's a kind of mental block for me - can somebody please suggest such mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping (well, one such mapping) is from the subset $S$ to the set of indices in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ which have an "a". For example, $\{1,2\}$ maps to "aabb," $\{1,4\}$ maps to "abba," et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

It works out fine in this case because you have $2$ groups of $2$ indistinguishable objects and $2+2 = 4$. I'll explain this in a minute.
Let's get to the mapping. For every ordered pair in problem $1$, you put an $a$ at the positions indicated by the pair. Mathematically, $\{x,y\}$ would imply an $a$ at $x$th position and another $a$ at $y$th position. The $b$'s would have be left with 2 spaces only, so they'll fit accordingly. Here's the mapping:
$$\{1,2\} \to aabb$$
$$\{1,3\} \to abab$$
$$\{1,4\} \to abba$$
$$\{2,3\} \to baab$$
$$\{2,4\} \to baba$$
$$\{3,4\} \to bbaa$$
This works because here:
$$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{a!b!}$$Or more specifically, $a = r = (n-r) = b$. You could also have chosen $3$ out of $6$ (problem $1$) and permuting $6$ (problem $2$)(where $3$ are of $1$ kind and $3$ of another kind in problem $2$),  giving the same answer, i.e,
$$\frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!} = \frac{6!}{3!3!}$$However, the  $a = r = (n-r) = b$ is a special case. You only need $a=r$ and $b = n-r$. For example:
Case 1: You want to make an unordered subset of $4$ (or $2$) elements from a set of $6$ distinguishable objects. There are $\binom{6}{4} = \binom{6}{2} = \frac{6!}{4!2!} = 15$ ways. The possible ways are  $\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,3,6\}, \{1,2,4,5\}, \{1,2,4,6\}, \{1,2,5,6\}, \{1,3,4,5\}, \{1,3,4,6\}, \{1,3,5,6\}, \{1,4,5,6\}, \{2,3,4,5\}, \{2,3,4,6\}, \{2,3,5,6\}, \{2,4,5,6\}, \{3,4,5,6\}$ (or $\{5,6\}, \{4,6\}, \{4,5\}, \{3,6\}, \{3,5\}, \{4,3\}, \{2,6\}, \{2,5\}, \{2,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,6\}, \{1,5\}, \{1,4\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2\}$ if you're choosing $2$ elements).


Case 2: Out of $6$ objects, $4$ are of 1 kind, and $2$ are of another kind. The total number of ways to permute them are $\frac{6!}{4!2!} = 15$ ways. The permutations are:
$bbaaaa, babaaa, baabaa, baaaba, baaaab, abbaaa, ababaa, abaaba, abaaab, aabbaa, aababa, aabaab, aaabba, aaabab, aaaabb$
 We can map these by placing an $a$ at each of the positions indicated by the subsets with $4$ elements (or you can place the $b$'s at the positions indicated by the subsets of $2$ elements):
$$\{1,2,3,4\} \to aaaabb$$
$$\{1,2,3,5\} \to aaabab$$
$$\{1,2,3,6\} \to aaabba$$
$$\{1,2,4,5\} \to aabaab$$
$$\{1,2,4,6\} \to aababa$$
$$\{1,2,5,6\} \to aabbaa$$
$$\{1,3,4,5\} \to abaaab$$
$$\{1,3,4,6\} \to abaaba$$
$$\{1,3,5,6\} \to ababaa$$
$$\{1,4,5,6\} \to abbaaa$$
$$\{2,3,4,5\} \to baaaab$$
$$\{2,3,4,6\} \to baaaba$$
$$\{2,3,5,6\} \to baabaa$$
$$\{2,4,5,6\} \to babaaa$$
$$\{3,4,5,6\} \to bbaaaa$$